# How to move Thunderbird profile from Windows to Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, windows-10, thunderbird

I am trying to move a Thunderbird profile from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 20.04.1. I have followed [Mozilla's instructions](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/moving-thunderbird-data-to-a-new-computer) several times, but they don't work. When I open Thunderbird after copying the profile folders, one of two things happens:

1. Either I am greeted by a "new installation" screen showing none of my folders or e-mail and inviting me to set up a new e-mail account.
2. Or I am greeted by this version-conflict error message saying "A newer version of Thunderbird may have made changes to your profile which are no longer compatible with this older version" and a link to [this page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/unable-launch-older-version-profile).

I'm not sure what version of Thunderbird I had running on Windows 10, but it was reasonably current. The version on Ubuntu is 68.10.0.

Either way, I am prevented from importing the profile or the thousands of locally stored e-mails in the profile. Any ideas how I can get this done?

Comment: Just copy everything in "Documents and Settings > {user name} > Application Data > Thunderbird" onto an USB stick. Remove in Ubuntu in `.thunderbird` the `profiles.ini`  and your profile directory (something like {randomchars}.default` and copy those over from the USB. That really should be it. I have done this dozens and dozens of times over the past years. (I checked your link after typing this ;-) one comment: do it from command line using "sudo" and not from the desktop and BEFORE removing the files from Ubuntu check the permissions it has now and match the new copy with them

Comment: ... the version on windows does not matter. All that matters is that you match the permissions: make sure the old file and folder that you delete match the permissions of the new file and the folder

Comment: Thanks. You were right that file permissions weren't set correctly, but unfortunately that did not fix the problem. I'm still getting the "profile...no longer compatible with this older version" error message.

Comment: Something odd: I tried "rm -rf .thunderbird" "sudo apt purge thunderbird" "sudo apt install thunderbird". Then, when I opened Thunderbird anew, it recreated empty profiles *with the same names* as the ones I had just (I thought) completely removed. I thought it assigned profile names randomly. Is there Thunderbird data stored somewhere outside the .thunderbird folder??

Comment: unlikely. everything user related needs to be in home.

Comment: That's what I thought. I'm giving up on this for now. If I figure it out, I will post an answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It used to be, that you just edited profiile.ini. But they now have two files with added info in them. So start a new profile & copy/edit profile.ini & profiles_shared.ini with your profile. If it only sees old profile.ini, it assumes an older version of Thunderbird. I also have to do the same with Firefox.

Comment: If you use Thunderbird 78 on windows, this will not work.

Comment: Your profile may contain a file named `compatibility.ini`, remove this file and you should be able to use your profile regardless of thunderbird version.

Answer (score 3):

Copying and renaming did not work at all for me as well. It's kind of a regression of Thunderbird I'd say.

I finally managed to import all my Thunderbird profiles successfully in one go using the Addon ImportExportTools NG.

You can add it under Addons in Thunderbird:

- Under Windows Thunderbird export your profiles under *Tools* ->  *ImportExportTools NG* -> *Export Profile* -> to a folder you can access from Ubuntu.
- In Ubuntu Thunderbird import it from *Tools* ->  *ImportExportTools NG* -> *Import Profile* -> select the folder and follow the instructions. In case there is no menu by default like in my case, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and it will show.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above worked with ImportExportTools NG.
Windows TB was 91.12.0,
Ubuntu TB was 91.11.0.

With clean TB install on Ub, the addon would not install until at least one account was present (known bug).

Then installed the addon on the windows TB, and did profile export to a USB.

On Ub I deleted the account added on TB.

Did import profile from the USB. It prompts for a profile name which can be anything (avoid profile name (eg as34ftdr5 ?)

Click next and TB tries import.

I had a couple of 'Thunderbird is not responding' messages so restarted TB but then it worked OK with all accounts present, local files, filter etc!

In ~/.thunderbird you will see the profile as xxxx.IETimport
The installs.ini and profiles.ini are also set consistently

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).